# Two inserts in same transaction where second insert depends on the first

Tags: mysql

Here are some pseudo code that illustrates what I currently do, but what I want to improve.

```
var id = db.exec("INSERT INTO table_a (name) VALUES('something');")
db.exec("INSERT INTO table_b (name,table_a_id) VALUES('something', $id);")
```

In this piece of code I do two inserts in one call to the server where the first db call inserts a row and returns the primary key for that specific row. The next insert uses this primary key id as a foreign key.

The problem is that this is two transactions and I want it to be in one. How can I achieve that?

Thanks a lot for helping me out!

Comment: What programming language are you using?  What objects are you creating to interact with the database?  There's a good chance that data access library has functionality for managing transactions.

Comment: Go and MySQL, https://github.com/Go-SQL-Driver/MySQL/

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Go, but it looks like after importing that driver (http://go-database-sql.org/importing.html) you should be able to use transactions natively (http://go-database-sql.org/modifying.html) by calling `db.Begin()` and using the resulting `Tx` object for your data-modifying operations, then calling `.Commit()` or `.Rollback()` on that object.